# How to render ANSI color text in markdown

Tags: shell, colors, markdown, ascii

I have some text like belows which comes from some log.

```
2021-11-30T08:28:15.7728097Z ##[group]Run call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
2021-11-30T08:28:15.7729237Z [36;1mcall "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"[0m
2021-11-30T08:28:15.7729938Z [36;1mmvn clean package -P native -DskipTests[0m
2021-11-30T08:28:15.7731200Z [36;1mresources\rcedit-x64.exe target/${APP_NAME}.exe --set-icon resources/app_icon.ico --set-file-version 0.0.1 --set-product-version 0.0.1  --set-version-string ProductName spring-boot-native-image --set-version-string LegalCopyright MIT[0m
2021-11-30T08:28:15.7732572Z [36;1mdir target[0m
2021-11-30T08:28:15.7764946Z shell: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.EXE /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "{0}""
2021-11-30T08:28:15.7765382Z env:
2021-11-30T08:28:15.7765975Z   APP_NAME: spring-boot-native-image
2021-11-30T08:28:15.7766682Z   JAVA_HOME: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\GraalVM\java11-windows-amd64-21.3.0\x64
2021-11-30T08:28:15.7767551Z   GRAALVM_HOME: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\GraalVM\java11-windows-amd64-21.3.0\x64
```

And I want to render it normally in github markdown, I haved tried

````
```bash
text here
```
````

or

````
```shell
text here
```
````

or

````
```cmd
text here
```
````

But none of them worked as expected.

I tried to `cat` the text in terminal which support [ANSI color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), the result is like this.

[image]

Comment: Markdown doesn't support colours. You could try `ansi2html` to keep them, in html format? I'm not sure if github will display them or not. [Repo](https://github.com/kilobyte/colorized-logs). `ansi2txt` is also good for removing them. Note also that terminal control sequences should only ever be printed if output is to a terminal. If a program saved a log like this to a file, it has a bug.